# fluentvalidation InclusiveBetween dynamically set range

Tags: model-view-controller, fluentvalidation

Im using FluentValidation

I would like to do a range validation using:

**InclusiveBetween**

```
  RuleFor(x => x.Height)
             .InclusiveBetween(x=> x.min, x.max).
```

I want to be able to get the 'from' and 'to' values dynamically from the model..rather than being hardcoded in the validator

Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: They updated the framework. Check the latest version of FluentValidation [link](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/built-in-validators.html#inclusivebetween-validator)

Answer (score 3):

Well, there's nothing in FluentValidation for that.

But you could write your own extension method (and validator), something like that (fast shot, so you'll have to make this better, but you've got the idea).

```
//the extension method
public static class ValidationExtensions
   {
        public static IRuleBuilder<T, TProperty> InclusiveBetween<T, TProperty>(this IRuleBuilder<T, TProperty> ruleBuilder, Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> fromExpression, Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> toExpression)
        {
           var fromFunc = leftExpression.Compile();
           var toFunc = rightExpression.Compile();
           return ruleBuilder.SetValidator(new InclusiveBetweenPropertyValidator(fromFunc.CoerceToNonGeneric(), fromExpression.GetMember(), toFunc.CoerceToNonGeneric(), toExpression.GetMember()));
        }
   }
```

Then the  Validator class

```
public class InclusiveBetweenPropertyValidator : PropertyValidator, IBetweenValidator, IPropertyValidator
{
    public  Func<object, object> FromFunc { get; set; }
    public MemberInfo FromMemberInfo { get; set; }

    public Func<object, object> ToFunc { get; set; }
    public MemberInfo ToMemberInfo { get; set; }

    public IComparable From { get; private set; }
    public IComparable To { get; private set; }

    public InclusiveBetweenPropertyValidator(Func<object, object> fromFunc, MemberInfo fromMember, Func<object, object> toFunc, MemberInfo toMember)
        : base((() => Messages.inclusivebetween_error))
    {
        FromFunc = fromFunc;
        FromMemberInfo = fromMember;
        ToFunc = toFunc;
        ToMemberInfo = toMember;
    }


    protected override bool IsValid(PropertyValidatorContext context)
    {
        var comparable = (IComparable)context.PropertyValue;
        From = (IComparable)this.FromFunc(context.Instance);
        To = (IComparable)this.ToFunc(context.Instance);

        if (comparable == null || FluentValidation.Internal.Comparer.GetComparisonResult(comparable, From) >= 0 && FluentValidation.Internal.Comparer.GetComparisonResult(comparable, To) <= 0)
            return true;
        context.MessageFormatter.AppendArgument("From", string.Format("{0} ({1})", FromMemberInfo.Name, From)).AppendArgument("To", string.Format("{0} ({1})",ToMemberInfo.Name, To)).AppendArgument("Value", context.PropertyValue);
        return false;
    }
}
```

usage :

```
RuleFor(x => x.Height)
             .InclusiveBetween(x=> x.min, x.max)
```

Comment: will this let you have automatic client side validation?

Comment: @raklos No idea. Big doubt, as in FluentValidation doc, it's stated that custom validators are not supported for client-side validation. But you may test...

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to write an extension you could use the additional overload of the [Predicate Validator](https://fluentvalidation.net/built-in-validators#predicate-validator) - which also accepts an instance of the parent object - like this:

```
RuleFor(x => x.Height)
    .Must((model, height) => height >= model.Min && height <= model.Max);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to Raphaël's answer, but is more of a case-by-case usage as opposed to a general usage extension.

`RuleFor(x => x).Must(HeightValidation);`

```
private static bool HeightValidation(Model m)
{
    return m.Height >= m.min && m.Height <= m.max;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's imagine your Model as follow:

```
public class YourModel
    {
        public int Height { get; set; }
        public int Min { get; set; }
        public int Max { get; set; }
    }
```

then Validation will be as follow:

```
public class YourModelValidation : AbstractValidator<YourModel>
    {
        public YourModelValidation(int min,int max)
        {
            RuleFor(x => x.Height).InclusiveBetween(min, max);
        }
    }
```

then Validation usage is :

```
var validation = new YourModelValidation(model.Min,model.Max).Validate(model);
```

as you can see dynamic parameters are passed in validation's Constructor.

you can pass  model or dto as Constructor parameter